# Apache AddOutputFilterByType is deprecated. How to rewrite using mod_filter?

Tags: apache

[AddOutputFilterByType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype) is deprecated in Apache.

The documentation says that the same functionality is available using [mod_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_filter.html).

I currently use

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
```

What is the equivalent using [mod_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_filter.html)?

Answer (score 18):

`AddOutputFilterByType` had severe limitations in `httpd-2.2` so it was marked deprecated there. But in `httpd-2.4` this directive was moved to `filter_module`, corrected and un-deprecated.

In apache 2.2 you should instead enable `filter_module` and `deflate_module` and use:

```
# Declare a "gzip" filter, it should run after all internal filters like PHP or SSI
FilterDeclare  gzip CONTENT_SET

# "gzip" filter can change "Content-Length", can not be used with range requests
FilterProtocol gzip change=yes;byteranges=no

# Enable "gzip" filter if "Content-Type" contains "text/html", "text/css" etc.
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/javascript
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
FilterProvider gzip DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-javascript

# Add "gzip" filter to the chain of filters
FilterChain    gzip
```

`deflate_module` would only serve compressed content to browsers that declare support for `gzip` encoding in request header.

Comment: This helped me bigtime. Just a heads up on FilterProvider: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1012

Comment: In Centos filter_module is not enabled by default. Needs to be uncommented.

Comment: This made ETags randomly be missing from gzipped responses.

Comment: Between this AddOutputFilterByType being deprecated then un-deprecated, and the two different incompatible syntaxes of FilterProvider, all of this is kind of a mess. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

I'm using `mod_filter` for substituing instead of deflating, but the idea is the same. 
This is what worked for me (I'm doing reverse proxy and rewriting urls and links):

```
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so

FilterDeclare MYFILTER
# syntax changed in Apache2.4  (see also  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html)  
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/xml'"
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/javascript'"
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"

<Location /sial/> 
  ProxyPass        http://localhost:8300/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8300/
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /sial/  
  FilterChain MYFILTER
  Substitute "s|/tea_sial_v2|/sial/tea_sial_v2|inq"
</Location>
```

Answer (score 6):

It become un-deprecated in Apache 2.3.7, because it was moved/integrated into `mod_filter`.  So, what I've got in:

Instead of:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c> 
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
```

using:

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
...
```