# [Apache2][mod_substitute][mod_filter] Substitute / Filter / Rewrite dynamic ProxyPassed HTML Content

Tags: html, apache, dynamic

We're trying to rewrite the HTML-Content (Links) of a ProxyPassed Website.
We've tried something like that: http://lamshing.blogspot.de/2010/10/on-fly-subsitution-of-text-with.html, but without avail.
And are now stuck with: [Apache AddOutputFilterByType is deprecated. How to rewrite using mod_filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230202/apache-addoutputfilterbytype-is-deprecated-how-to-rewrite-using-mod-filter)

Conent in included files (like a *.css) gets substituted, but not "root" content.
We've read, that ProxyPassed content has an "unkown type" -> The filters won't take effect.

Do you guys have any clue, how one could be able to substitute something in a dynamic AND ProxyPassed environment?

Our current config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Header set TEST ";charset=utf-8"
Header edit TEST ^\s*;charset=utf-8\s*$ "text/html; charset=utf-8"

FilterDeclare MYFILTER
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $*
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/xml
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/json
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE resp=Content-Type $/javascript
        <Location />
                FilterChain MYFILTER
                Substitute "s/You have/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/ni"
        </Location>
        RewriteEngine On
        ServerSignature Off



        ProxyRequests Off


        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass / http://hmpg.net/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://hmpg.net/


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it working, gzip was the problem.

In the Location / add:

RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

Use no FilterChain and just add your Substitute like:

"foo1337=k,bar=k"

Substitute "s|foo([0-9]+)=k,bar\1=k|foo/bar=$1"

-> "foo/bar=1337"

Comment: Thanks so much for this tip! It belongs in the docs for mod_substitute!

Answer (score 0):

take care on new FilterProvider Parametersettings e.g.:

```
FilterProvider MYFILTER SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} =~ |^text/html|"
```