# .htaccess 500 Internal server Error in wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Hi I am getting 500 Internal  server Error when am trying to run my code in wampserver which is working absolutely 
My .htaccess file is in wamp/www/site foloder and all other code is also in same folder
so should i put site somewhere in .htaccess file because online my code is in root folder
My .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
FileETag none

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript 
</IfModule>
```

Apache error is here:

> J:/wamp/www/site/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: /site/about/

Comment: RewriteEngine on
FileETag none

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

Comment: `AddOutputFilterByType` is now deprecated, depending on your config this may be the cause. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230202/apache-addoutputfilterbytype-is-deprecated-how-to-rewrite-using-mod-filter for more info

Comment: Comment out `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` block

Answer (score 4):

If you are using apache 2.4, you need to change

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
```

as the output filter has been moved to mod_filter. Then you need to make sure you have mod_filter loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help It is working fine now but I am not getting any css files or jQuery files in the page....

Comment: @MPatel make sure your links are either absolute URLs or you have a `<base href="/" />` in the header of your page